Autofill Google Doc From Form not working; GSheet also stops updating new form responses
I want to automatically copy incoming Google Form responses to a Google Doc. For this, I followed Jeffrey Everhart's tutorial step by step. I then tried submitting a new response, but no Google Doc was generated in the destination folder. More than that, the new response did not reflect in the linked Google Sheet; I can only view it in the Google Form responses page. This is the code I used, if it helps diagnosing the problem:
function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var upMail = e.values[1];
  var agreement = e.values[2];
  var fullName = e.values[3];
  var livedName = e.values[4];
  var pronouns = e.values[5];
  var age = e.values[6];
  var birthday = e.values[7];
  var contactNumber = e.values[8];
  var altEmail = e.values[9];
  var degreeProgram = e.values[10];
  var yearLevel = e.values[11];
  var facebookLink = e.values[12];
  var voiceLesson = e.values[13];
  var singingExp = e.values[14];
  var others = e.values[15];
  var graphicDesign = e.values[16];
  var aof = e.values[17];
  var screeningDateA = e.values[18];
  var screeningDateB = e.values[19];

  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("19AYo5zEij9iWAN5pBaV8HNgaCwqsaRGvpDYd9X_p1rg");
  var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1S1yBfh6W30YQD5Jnd72dD8wREVkQund-");

  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(fullName,templateResponseFolder);
  
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.replaceText("{{AOF}}", aof);
  body.replaceText("{{Name}}", fullName);
  body.replaceText("{{Pronouns}}", pronouns);
  body.replaceText("{{Year}}", yearLevel);
  body.replaceText("{{Course}}", degreeProgram);
  body.replaceText("{{LivedName}}", livedName);
  body.replaceText("{{Age}}", age);
  body.replaceText("{{Birthday}}", birthday);
  body.replaceText("{{ContactNumber}}", contactNumber);
  body.replaceText("{{AltMail}}", altEmail);
  body.replaceText("{{Facebook}}", facebookLink);
  body.replaceText("{{UPMail}}", upMail);
  body.replaceText("{{VoiceLesson}}", voiceLesson);
  body.replaceText("{{SingingExp}}", singingExp);
  body.replaceText("{{Others}}", others);
  body.replaceText("{{GraphicDesign}}", graphicDesign);
  
  doc.saveAndClose();
}

I tried resubmitting new responses and refreshing the GSheet as well as the destination folder for the Google Doc, to no avail. I am not very adept with coding as this is only my second time trying to work something out using coding.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question needs to include more details, as it does not provide information on the form, the spreadsheet, the trigger, or how the script is run and the execution logs. Regarding the link included, while it might help, please keep in mind that questions on this site should be self-contained, so you should include a summary and all the relevant details required to reproduce the problem.

If the spreadsheet has stopped receiving form submissions, please review it to ensure the form is still linked to the spreadsheet containing the code. By the way, this is not a programming problem. It might be caused by something broken by the form and spreadsheet owner / editors or a service glitch / bug.

I made a simpler version but did exactly the same thing and it worked the very first time.
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));//check to make sure your getting the event object look in execution log
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var v1 = e.values[1];
  var v2 = e.values[2];
  var v3 = e.values[3];
  var v4 = e.values[4];
  var v5 = e.values[5];
  var testdoc = DriveApp.getFileById(gobj.globals.testdocid);//these are just global ids
  var folder1 = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.folder1id);
  var copy = testdoc.makeCopy(v3,folder1);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{{COL1}}", v1);
  body.replaceText("{{COL2}}", v2);
  body.replaceText("{{COL3}}", v3);
  body.replaceText("{{COL4}}", v4);
  body.replaceText("{{COL5}}", v5);
  doc.saveAndClose();
}

Try using Logger.log to check where you are going wrong.  And you might start with a simpler version of that code just to get it running.

Hi, Cooper! Thank you for this. I found out that the problem was indeed not a programming problem, like what Wicket said. I was just a collaborator on the Google Form and Google Sheet (I had access to it), but not the direct owner of the form and the sheet. I tried making my own form, went through the whole process for the autofill again, and it worked. Thank you all so much for your help!
